# getDefaultSharedPreferences not Saving Between Services

Tags: android, service, sharedpreferences

I have two services (a DashClock extension service that calls another service), and the second service is supposed to save a value so I can use that value to display in my DashClock extension.  However, this value does not appear to be passed into the extension service.

DashClock Extension:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    be=this;
    //numUpdates = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("numUpdates", -1);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, UpdateCheckService.class);
    i.putExtra(Constants.CHECK_FOR_UPDATE, true);
    startService(i);
    //numUpdates = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("numUpdates", 0);

    registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK));
}

@Override
protected void onUpdateData(int reason) {
    // Get preference value.
    final SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    //String name = sp.getString(PREF_NAME, "Eric");
    Log.d("hiya","updating");
    /*while(getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("numUpdates", -1)==-1){
        Log.d("wait","waiting here");
    }*/
    //numUpdates = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("numUpdates", -2);
    int numUpdates = sp.getInt("numUpdates", -2);
    Log.d("IMPORTANT FROM BrianExtension", "" + numUpdates);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClassName("com.cyanogenmod.updater", "com.cyanogenmod.updater.UpdatesSettings");
    // Publish the extension data update.
    if(numUpdates == 0){
        shouldShow = false;
    } else{
        shouldShow = true;
    }
    publishUpdate(new ExtensionData()
            .visible(shouldShow)
            .icon(R.drawable.cid)
            .status(numUpdates + " updates")
            .expandedTitle(numUpdates + " Nightly CM Updates")
            .expandedBody("Click here to go to CMUpdater.")
            .clickIntent(intent));
}
```

UpdateCheckService:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    ucs = this;
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter("updatethis"));
    /*prefs = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(mListener);*/
    final SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                try {
                    int ericUpdates = getAvailableUpdates().getUpdateCount(getBaseContext());
                    Log.d("yes!", ""+ericUpdates);
                    sp.edit().putInt("numUpdates", ericUpdates).apply();
                    Log.d("IMPORTANT FROM UpdateCheckService", "" + sp.getInt("numUpdates", -99));
                    //getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putInt("numUpdates", ericUpdates).apply();
                    //Log.d("IMPORTANT FROM UpdateCheckService", "" + getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("numUpdates", -99));
                    sendBroadcast(new Intent(ucs, BrianUpdaterReceiver.class));
                    //BrianExtension.be.onUpdateData(4);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
    //stopSelf();
    // Get the System Mod string
    mSystemMod = TESTING_DOWNLOAD ? "cmtestdevice" : SysUtils.getSystemProperty(Customization.BOARD);
    if (mSystemMod == null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Unable to determine System's Mod version. Updater will show all available updates");
    }
}
```

The logs show that the value in the "numUpdates" preference is correct in the UpdateCheckService but remains -2 in the BrianExtension.

manifest entries:

```
<service android:name=".BrianExtension"
        android:icon="@drawable/cid"
        android:label="CyanogenMod Updates"
        android:permission="com.google.android.apps.dashclock.permission.READ_EXTENSION_DATA">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.apps.dashclock.Extension" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="protocolVersion" android:value="1" />
        <meta-data android:name="description"
            android:value="Displays Number of New Nightly Updates Available" />
    </service>

<service android:name="com.brianco.cyanogenmodupdatecheckfordashclock.UpdateCheckService"
             android:process="com.brianco.cyanogenmodupdatecheckfordashclock.UpdateCheckService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.brianco.cyanogenmodupdatecheckfordashclock.IUpdateCheckService"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Comment: Post your manifest entries for the two `<service>` elements.

Comment: Are you running services in different processes?

Comment: I think they are in different processes.  Is that a problem?

Comment: Okay, I just removed the android:process line in the second service's declaration in the manifest, and it looks like it is working.  First, why is it now working?  Second, will removing that line break anything possibly?

Comment: yes. preferences will not be shared between processes. You will have to use a database I think.

Comment: Normally you dont need to run services in different processes unless it is required for some special purpose. Hopefully it wont affect your code if you haven't put it for a reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First, why is it now working?

Because you were using two separate processes. `SharedPreferences` are read in initially, then are effectively write-only for the rest of the process' lifetime. For two processes running simultaneously, one process cannot see the other process' changes.

> Second, will removing that line break anything possibly?

Not only will it not break things, but it will make your app faster, consume less system RAM, and generally be better for the user.

Comment: Thanks so much!  This was driving me crazy haha.